# Troubleshooting an empty HTML console log bar in Django with Python asyncio

Tags: python, html, django, console

HTML console log bar is empty.

I was trying to redirect the log messages from my terminal to an HTML console log on my Django webpage. the console log bar is created in the html page but is empty, not showing the log messages. i wanted to create a log console on upload.html that simply redirects each and every message that comes in my terminal of vscode to html. I tried the following code:

in views.py:

```
def home(request):
    return render (request, 'index.html')

tracemalloc.start()

ws_connection = None
log_queue = asyncio.Queue()

async def log_consumer():
    while True:
        message = await log_queue.get()
        if ws_connection is not None:
            await ws_connection.send(message)

def progress_callback(message, progress):
    sys.stdout.write(message + ' Progress: ' + str(progress) + '%\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    asyncio.create_task(log_queue.put(f"{message} Progress: {progress}%"))
    
def calculate_features(file_path):
    total_steps = 10
    completed_steps = 0
    # Use os.path.abspath to get the absolute file path
    file_path = os.path.abspath(file_path)
    MERGED_DATAFRAMES = []
    with open(file_path) as fasta_file:
        parser = fastaparser.Reader(fasta_file)
        seq_num = 1
        ID_list = []
        list_data = []
        for seq in parser:
            ID = seq.id
            sequence = seq.formatted_fasta()
            sequence1 = seq.sequence_as_string()
            ID_list.append(ID)
            df_ID = pd.DataFrame(ID_list, columns=['ID'])
            completed_steps += 1
            progress=int((completed_steps / total_steps) * 100)
            progress_callback(f"Sequence {ID} uploaded successfully", progress)
    return progress

async def log(request):
    global ws_connection
    websocket = await websockets.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/log/')
    ws_connection = websocket
    await log_consumer()

async def upload_sequence(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        sequence = request.POST.get("sequence")
        #sequence = sequence.replace("\n", "")
        file = request.FILES.get("file")

        try:
            if sequence:
                script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
                file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "sequences.fasta")

                with open(file_path, "w") as f:
                    f.write(sequence)
            elif file:
                script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
                file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "sequences.fasta")
                with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
                    for chunk in file.chunks():
                        f.write(chunk)

            asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
            calculate_features(file_path)
            

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error analyzing sequence: {e}")
            await log_queue.put("Error analyzing sequence")
            return JsonResponse({"status": "Error analyzing sequence"}, status=500)

        return redirect("results")
        
    return render(request, "upload.html")
```

in upload.html:

```
    <h3>Enter your Protein sequences OR Select your fasta file *</h3>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label style="margin-left: 5%;" for="specie_select">Select the pathogen:</label>
        <select name="category" id="category">
          <option value="option1">Enterococcus faecium</option>
          <option value="option2">Staphylococcus aureus</option>
          <option value="option3">Klebsiella pneumoniae</option>
          <option value="option3">Acinetobacter baumannii</option>
          <option value="option3">Pseudomonas aeruginosa</option>
          <option value="option3">Enterobacter spp</option>
        </select><br><br>

        <textarea name="sequence" rows="8" cols="135"></textarea><br><br>

        <label style="margin-left: 5%;" for="file">File:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file-input"><br><br>

        <input type="hidden" name="rendered_output" value="{{ rendered_output|safe }}">

        <input style="width: 80%; height: 35px; background-color:#091E34; color: #ffff; margin-left: 5%;" type="submit" value="upload", id="uploadbutton">
    </form>
    <div id="console-log"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Establish WebSocket connection
        const socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/log/');

        // Event handler for WebSocket connection opened
        socket.onopen = () => {
            console.log('WebSocket connection opened');
        };

        // Event handler for WebSocket connection closed
        socket.onclose = () => {
            console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
        };

        // Event handler for receiving messages from the server
        socket.onmessage = (event) => {
            const message = event.data;
            // Update the UI with the received log message
            const logElement = document.getElementById('log');
            logElement.innerHTML += message + '<br>';
        };

        // Function to send a message to the server via WebSocket
        function sendMessage(message) {
            if (socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                socket.send(message);
            } else {
                console.log('WebSocket connection is not open');
            }
        }
    </script>
```